# Selenium how to click modal close button

Tags: python, css, selenium

I tried many combinations but couldn't manage to click on the X button to close the modal window.

According to the html code below

```
<div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="far fa-times"></i>
                </div>
```

What string should i pass below for finding the element by css selector?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML you are sharing in the question the CSS Selector you should use can be

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(div.modal-close)
```

However I can't be sure about it since I can't check if this locator is unique etc.
Also you possibly should use some wait / delay before using this command.

Answer (score 0):

I moved from css_selector to class_name

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("modal-close").click()
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a click action with selenium, you should store the element to click, `close = drive.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-close')`.
After you store the element, you should be able to click it using `.click()`:
`close.click()`
If you don't want to store it, simply call: `drive.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-close').click()`.